# Why ngc partially ignore compileroptions.outDir? Does a workaround exist?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `tsconfig.json` which specifies an `outDir`. The reason is that I want to separate the generated JavaScript output from the TypeScript sources.

So:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "target/",
    ...
}
```

This works very well, until I compile the project with the typescript compiler only. All generated javascript output is created in the `target/` directory.

But, if I call it with the angular compiler (`ngc`, it is essentially a wrapper around the `tsc` typescript compiler), we have an additional build step. It compiles the template files and components into typescript, which will be compiled further to javascript by the `tsc`.

These intermediary typescript files have the `*.ngfactory.ts` or `*.ngsummary.json` extension.

Now my problem is, that the `ngc` command generates these files still in my `src/` directory, totally ignoring my `outDir` setting in my `tsconfig.json`.

What is the cause of this problem? Does any useful workaround exist?

---

Extension: regarding comments, `ng` from the angular-cli *can* do this. This leads to a side-question, how does it do with the ngc?

Comment: Actually, I am shocked that on the google, I am the first facing this problem.

Comment: You put the tag angular-cli but you seem to bypass it by calling directly `ngc`. Why don't you use the more "friendly" CLI which should take care of that ? eg `ng build`

Comment: @bviale Thanks! The ngc is called by a more complex buildscript. (It is a complex app using d3 and angular coincidentally). `ng build` would do this really well? How can it do that `ngc` works really correctly in its case?

Comment: @bviale I am sorry, but `ng` is a monster for me. It has a lot of dependencies (f.e. sass, what is also platform-dependant) what I don't use. `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler-cli` are different things, I use only the second. I am experimenting with `ng`, but the problem is still open.

Comment: I have never used `ngc` directly so i cannot help with that (I also have to admin that I have not seen a lot of project using it). All I can suggest you is to give a try at `ng` which has a good documentation and an active github page if you encounter problems using it

Comment: @bviale Can I do with `ng build` that it creates the intermediate file in a target/ directory and and not beside the sources? Does it have a watch / incremental mode?

Comment: Yes, there is options for that : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that `ngc` has some additional options in `tsconfig.json` what I didn't add.

The following settings in `tsconfig.json` do what I want.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
}
```